# CakePHP 3.0 ORM - debug works, flip to live, throws errors

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I could use a sanity check here ...

I have a custom property in my Cake3.0 CustomersTable object

//CustomersTable

```
public $paginatorDefaults = [
    'conditions' => [...],
    'contain' => [...]
    ... etc
];
```

I use this from a global API ajax/json controller in order to read pagination that I can set per Model

//ApiController -

```
//Load the components
public $components = [
    'RequestHandler', 
    'Paginator'
];


//Initialize the dynamic table object
public function initialize() {
  parent::initialize();
  //Set tableName
  $this->_tableName = $this->findTable(Inflector::camelize($this->request->model));
  //Instantiate table
  $this->_table = $this->loadModel($this->_tableName);
}

public function index() {
  $pagination = $this->_pagination(); //Loads the 
  $entities = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->_table->find(), $this->_table->paginatorDefaults);
  $this->set([
    'data' => $entities,
    'request' => $this->request,
    '_serialize' => ['data','request'],
  ]);
}
```

On the client side I am calling this via the Angular-based Ajax request, which has been configured to send the X-Requested-With header to trigger Cake's isAjax() handling and I'm sending requests to the .json extended Cake path to request JSON data in response.

So, when Config/app.php debug = true, everything works tickety-boo - it correctly returns the entity data. But if I toggle the debug to false, I now get ORM errors in my error log.

## Error: [RuntimeException] Table "Cake\ORM\Table" is not associated with "paginatorDefaults"

```
2014-10-24 16:49:44 Error: [RuntimeException] Table "Cake\ORM\Table" is not associated with "paginatorDefaults"
Request URL: /Tremendus/Momento/api/customers.json?sort=Customers.name&direction=asc&limit=10&page=1
Stack Trace:
0 /<masked path>/plugins/Api/src/Controller/ApiController.php(92): Cake\ORM\Table->__get('paginatorDefaul...')
1 /<masked path>/plugins/Api/src/Controller/ApiController.php(78): Api\Controller\ApiController->_pagination()
2 [internal function]: Api\Controller\ApiController->index()
3 /<masked path>/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(411): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
4 /<masked path>/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(111): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
5 /<masked path>/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(85): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(Api\Controller\ApiController))
6 /<masked path>/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
7 {main}
```

So, I have found no reason why I cannot set arbitrary properties on the Table object - indeed it works fine in debug - but why not when I flip it off?

(PS: I have purged all app/tmp cache files.)

Answer (score 0):

The paginator in 3.0 does not work the same as in 2.0. The second argument is not meant to pass options to the query. You have 2 options

```
$this->paginate = $this->_table->paginatorDefaults
```

That will set the options for the paginator to be the same as what you have stored for the table. You can alternatively use find() to hold those defaults for you:

```
$this->paginate($this->_table->find('all', $this->_table->paginatorDefaults));
```

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for reaching out with a reply, I'm sure your busy, I appreciate your time.     This has not solved the problem however. There is still something fishy between live and debug modes. In the end I refactored the defaults at the table class to use custom find methods (method = findStandard()). Controller is updated to use $this->paginate['finder' => 'standard'] and $this->paginate($this->_table) - everything works just find when debug is ON, but with only one change - debug = off - cake throws error - "Unknown finder method "standard"" - yet it works when debug = on ... ?

Comment: That sounds like in debug = false some sort of cache is making your app load another table file or not find your table file correctly. do a var_dump() of the table object when debug = false and verify it is what you expect it to be

Comment: No ... it's not as simple as that. Cache is off and dumped, tmp files are cleaned each request. Still the same result. I'm digging through core library files now. I'm have a feeling it's something in the requestHandler as it only does it when I request .json extension with the requestHandler component loaded. It might be routing related ... (But even then why would it work with debug on and not with debug off) I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Jose, should the RequestHandler strip the .json extension from the method or param? (whatever is the last element in the URL) Currently, it does this as expected with debug on. But it does NOT do it when debug is off. Am I missing something or is that expected behavior? Have I got a misconfiguration?

Comment: Yeah, we found the .json bug just recently. A fix in on the works :)